# Passing key value pairs to a class with pgfopts

Tags: pgfkeys, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to pass a key-value-pair to a class using pgfopts. The file `testclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[A Testclass]

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

\pgfkeys{testclass/testkey/.initial=testkeyinitial}
\pgfkeys{testclass/.is family}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/testclass}

\pgfkeys{testclass, testkey/.get=\optiontest}
```

And the file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[testkey=Works!]{testclass}

\begin{document}
\optiontest
\end{document}
```

Trying to compile `test.tex` gives the following error:

```
(./testclass.cls
Document Class: testclass A Testclass
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty))
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               A
 l.2 

 ?
```

When slightly change the above from class to package it works ...
what am I missing? Many thanks in advance! Is it not possible to use pgfopts with classes?

Comment: You need to start the optional argument to `\ProvidesClass` with a date ...

Comment: @Joseph Wright Thank you very much, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for `\ProvidesClass` requires that the first part of the optional 'description' argument is a date in the form `YYYY/MM/DD`. There's no check that this is there something of the right form: the required text is passed through directly to be used as numbers. As such, if there are no numbers things go wrong, as you've seen. So the fix is to either omit the optional argument or to include something of the right form (can be `0000/00/00`).